Hot reload for Axum in Rust
I am trying to learn rust with axum. As I am from scala playramework background, I strongly feel the necessity of hot reload or incremental compilation in Rust Axum. Since I am very new in rust world, I feel I am lacking some knowledge in this regard in rust. Is there any way of using hot reload  or incremental compilation in rust axum?
Thank you.

Use cargo watch, it is not incremental I believe but it will be a continuous loop to speed things up a bit.

Cargo already does quite extensive incremental compilation out of the box.
